# How to return the complete list when the input is empty?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The search filter works practically as I wish, you enter a city and when you press the button it returns the results of the clinics that match the list of cities. The only problem is that I can only do a single search, then I have to reload the page, I need to delete the city from the input so that the complete list appears again and I can do another search, using typescript is complicating this part. To make it clearer, what I am trying to do is that whenever I enter a new city in the search bar and press the button, I get the result of the clinics in that city, now it just gives me the result only once, the next search gives me the result of clinic not found.

```
import React,  { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getClinic } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Clinic} from '@icofcv/common';
import contentUtils from '../../lib/contentUtils'
import Loader from '../spinner/Loader';



interface Props {
    showModalLocator: boolean,
    closeModalLocator: () => void
}


export const ClinicLocator: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, showModalLocator, closeModalLocator }) => {

     const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[] | undefined >([]);
    const [text, setText] = useState("")

    const textInput = () => {
        text === "" ? clinicList : null
    }

    const fetchClinicList = async () => {
    getClinic().then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
        setClinicList(response)
    }).catch ( (error)  => {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    });
}

    const handleChange = () => {
        const filterClinicList = clinicList && clinicList?.length > 0
        ? clinicList?.filter((clinic) => clinic?.province?.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()) 
        : undefined;
       
       
        setClinicList(filterClinicList)
        
    }

    useEffect (() => {
    fetchClinicList();  
     }, []);



return (
        <>
              <div>
                {showModalLocator ? (
                    <>
                        <div className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
                            <div className="relative p-2 w-full max-w-3xl h-full md:h-auto">
                                {/*content*/}
                                <div className="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow">
                                    {/*header*/}
                                    <div className="flex justify-between items-start px-4 py-3 rounded-t border-b">
                                        <h3 className="text-lg font-medium">Localizador de clinicas</h3>
                                        <button className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center" onClick={closeModalLocator}>
                                            <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                            </svg>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    {/*body*/}
                                    <div className="relative px-3 py-3 flex-auto overflow-auto modal-body">
                                        <h2 className="text-sm font-medium mb-2">¿Dónde te encuentras?</h2>
                                        <input 
                                         value={text}
                                        onChange= {(e) =>  {setText(e.target.value)
                                        textInput}}
                                        type="search" 
                                        className="w-100 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block p-2" 
                                        placeholder="Introduce una ubicación"
                                        />
<div>
                                            <h2 className="text-sm font-medium my-3">Resultados</h2>
                                            <div className="w-100">
                                                <iframe className="w-100" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2664.3238269926374!2d-0.3805919350162851!3d39.46959682083709!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd604f4bee0957f3%3A0x6686ff7d230b3965!2zQy4gZGUgU2FudC
                                                BWaWNlbnQgTcOgcnRpciwgNjEsIHBpc28gMsK6LCBwdGEgMsKqLCA0NjAwMiBWYWzDqG5jaWEsIEVzcGHDsWE!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sus!4v1662388390673!5m2!1ses!2sus" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="md:mt-4 overflow-auto relative py-2">
                                                <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-2">
{clinicList && clinicList?.length === 0 && (
                                                       <div>Clinica no encontrada</div>
                                                   )}
                                                   
                                                        {!clinicList ? <Loader /> :
                                                            clinicList.map((clinicFilter) => (
                                                     <div className="card bg-white px-2 py-3 h-36 md:h-32">
                                                        <button key={clinicFilter.id} type="button" className="text-left">
                                                            <div className="flex items-center gap-2 md:gap-4 md:gap-4">
                                                                <img className="h-24 w-2/5 min-w-40 object-cover object-center rounded-lg" src={contentUtils.getLargeImageUrl(clinicFilter.logo)} alt="#"/>
                                                                <div className="w-3/5">
                                                                    <div className="text-md font-medium leading-5 clinic-title uppercase">{clinicFilter.title}</div>
                                                                    <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                                                                        <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinicFilter.propsPhone}</div>
                                                                        <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinicFilter.mobile}</div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div className="text-teal-600 text-sm underline clinic-mail">{clinicFilter.email}</div>
                                                                    <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinicFilter.registry}</div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </button>
                                                        </div>
                                                            ))
                                                        }
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                         {/*footer*/}
                                    <div className="flex items-center justify-end px-4 py-2 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b gap-2">
                                        <button className="btn text-black text-sm background-transparent px-8 outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-teal-600 focus:border-teal-600" type="button" onClick={closeModalLocator}>Cancelar</button>
                                        <button className="btn bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white text-sm active:bg-teal-700 px-8 outline-none focus:outline-none" type="button" onClick={handleChange} >Buscar</button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                   
                                </div>
     </div>
                        
                        <div className="opacity-25 fixed inset-0 z-40 bg-black"></div>
                    </>
                ) : null}

            </div>

       </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure when exactly you want to reset the input but basically - `setText('')`.

Comment: Hi , you're saying what is the issue and not why that is an issue. Please explain what you're trying to do and then state the errors you're facing

Comment: In your search function, you should return list of all clinics when no input is received. Filter if text input is there else return clinicList

Answer (score 0):

In your handleChange just return the List itself when text is null

````
 const filterClinicList = clinicList && clinicList?.length > 0
        ? clinicList?.filter((clinic) => (!text || clinic?.province?.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase())) 
        : undefined; //!text evaluates to true when text is '' i.e. short circuit the filter
```

ideally what you do would be:
```
let filterClinicList = clinicList;

//only filter when you *need* to filter
if (text) {
    filterClinicList = clinicList?.filter((clinic) => (!text || clinic?.province?.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()));
}
```
````